# Bitcoin library - how to check number of confirmations

Tags: address

when I use bx fetch-balance I get this output:

> $ bx fetch-balance 1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa
>
> balance {
>       address 1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa
>       confirmed 1538241483
>       received 6538241483
>       unspent 6538241483 }

it doesn't show the number of confirmations.

how can I check the number of confirmations using bx command?

Comment: Is this a bitcoin core api ?

Comment: `bx` is libbitcoin-explorer: https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer

Answer (score 2):

"confirmed" in this case means the transaction is included in at least one block that belongs to the current best chain.

If you want to find out exactly how many confirmations each transaction has you can use `fetch-history` to get a full list of all transactions sent to and from your address. `fetch-history` will return the block number that the transaction has been included in. You can then use that along with the current height to figure out how many confirmations your transaction has.

```
bx fetch-history 1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa
bx fetch-height
```